# Insert text after dynamically created table in word using VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

How using VSTO and Word 2003 can I insert text after a table I've created? I have code like

```
bookmarkDescriptions = (object)"bookmarkDescriptions";
Word.Range rangeDescriptions = aDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkDescriptions).Range;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    //Add a paragraph with some text
    Table descTable = aDoc.Tables.Add(oSelection.Range, 1, 2, ref missing, ref missing);
    //Insert some text into the cells
    //Add a another paragraph with some text
}
```

when I add another paragraph of text it's added within the table but I want it after the table. Since I need to loop over all items and create some text - paragraph - some more text for each of them I don't see how I could make use of a bookmark to get a range after and outside the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved the problem. I am using the following code.

```
object oLineUnit = (object) Word.WdUnits.wdLine;
object oCountOne = (object) 1;
object oCellUnit = (object) Word.WdUnits.wdCell;

oSelection.MoveRight(ref oCellUnit, ref missing, ref missing);
oSelection.MoveDown(ref oLineUnit, ref oCountTwo, ref missing);
```

The best way to make sense of the Word object model seems to be to record a macro in Word and to then look at the source code so see what API calls are being made and to then replicate that in your enviroment of choice, hth.